# How to fill a big array of structs

Tags: solidity, gas, arrays, out-of-gas, struct

I'm quite new to Solidity and want to fill an array with 240 structs.

I have a struct:

```
    struct Country {
      string name;
      uint level;
      uint attackPower;
      uint defensePower;
      uint price;
   }
```

And an array:

```
    Country[] public countries;
```

I want to fill the array with Countries on deployment but when I try to do that as such my gas runs out and the contract can't even be deployed (even when not calling the function). What is the correct way of achieving my goal?

```
function createCountries() public{
    countries[0] = Country("AW",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[1] = Country("AF",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[2] = Country("AO",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[3] = Country("AI",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[4] = Country("AL",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[5] = Country("AX",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[6] = Country("AD",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[7] = Country("AE",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[8] = Country("AR",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[9] = Country("AM",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[10] = Country("AS",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[11] = Country("AQ",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[13] = Country("TF",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[14] = Country("AG",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[15] = Country("AU",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[16] = Country("AT",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[17] = Country("AZ",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[18] = Country("BI",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[19] = Country("BE",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[20] = Country("BJ",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[21] = Country("BF",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[22] = Country("BD",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[23] = Country("BG",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[24] = Country("BH",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[25] = Country("BS",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[26] = Country("BA",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[27] = Country("BL",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[28] = Country("BY",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[29] = Country("BZ",1, 100, 100, 1);
    countries[30] = Country("BM",1, 100, 100, 1);
    ... 210 more of these...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in batches, and make use of the fact that every instantiation of a Country is almost the same.

I created this contract as an example:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.23;

contract CountryStore {
    bool public finishedCreating = false;

    mapping(bytes2 => Country) public createCountries;

    struct Country {
      string name;
      uint level;
      uint attackPower;
      uint defensePower;
      uint price;
      bool created;
    }

    Country[] public countries;

    function createCountries(string names) public onlyWhileCreating {
       for(uint256 i = 0; i < bytes(names).length; i+=2){
           // Get the next two characters and store them in `name`
           bytes memory name = new bytes(2);
           name[0] = bytes(names)[i];
           name[1] = bytes(names)[i+1];

           if(!createCountries(bytes2(name)).created)
               countries.push(Country({
                   name: string(name),
                   level: 1,
                   attackPower: 100,
                   defensePower: 100,
                   price: 1,
                   created: true
               }));
       }
    }

    function finishCreating() public {
        finishedCreating = true;
    }

    modifier onlyWhileCreating(){
       require(!finishedCreating, "This method can only be called when creating countries");
       _;
    }
}
```

It keeps track of every country created, so you avoid duplicates. Also, when you're done, you can call `setFinished` to disable `createCountries`.

Now, when you fill the `countries` array, call `createCountries` with the countrycodes concatenated. In Web3.js:

```
await countryStore.createCountries("AWAFAOAIALAXADAEAR") ....
```

Comment: This is an answer for this situation! But i would want my other Struct attributes to be variable as well this wouldnt work anymore right?

Comment: That's true, it won't work for every situation. Still, the gist of it is that you should instantiate `countries` in batches, not all at once.